# merge (combine) rows by column names (not by column values)

Tags: r, merge, rows

I have several R data frames. There are some columns with common column names, but there are also some columns with differing names in each data frames. I would like to combine rows of these data frames, so that the columns with the same names are added with new rows, and the columns with the differing column names can be kept in the new data frame. A replicable example would look something like this:

```
apple <- data.frame(Obs = c(1:4),
                    Color = c("red", "red", "red", "green"),
                    Weight = c(1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4))

orange <- data.frame(Obs = c(2:11),
                     speed = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 3))

apple
  Obs Color Weight
1   1   red    1.1
2   2   red    1.2
3   3   red    1.3
4   4 green    1.4

orange
   Obs speed
1    2     2
2    3     3
3    4     4
4    5     5
5    6     6
6    7     7
7    8     8
8    9     9
9   10     2
10  11     3
```

The desired output would look like this:

```
   Obs Color Weight speed
1   1   red    1.1
2   2   red    1.2
3   3   red    1.3
4   4 green    1.4
5   2                 2
6   3                 3
7   4                 4
8   5                 5
9   6                 6
10  7                 7
11  8                 8  
12  9                 9
13  10                2
14  11                3
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Wondering if you really just want to bind rows or not rather merge the data, e.g. Obs 2, 3 and 4 are in both data frames, so you could just append the speed information for these obs at the top and don#t add these Obs twice? Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(apple, orange)
```

which gives:

```
   Obs Color Weight speed
1    1   red    1.1    NA
2    2   red    1.2    NA
3    3   red    1.3    NA
4    4 green    1.4    NA
5    2  <NA>     NA     2
6    3  <NA>     NA     3
7    4  <NA>     NA     4
8    5  <NA>     NA     5
9    6  <NA>     NA     6
10   7  <NA>     NA     7
11   8  <NA>     NA     8
12   9  <NA>     NA     9
13  10  <NA>     NA     2
14  11  <NA>     NA     3
```

Answer (score 0):

The package `plyr` has a useful function for this:

```
library(plyr)
rbind.fill(apple, orange)
```

Giving the following table:

```
   Obs Color Weight speed
1    1   red    1.1    NA
2    2   red    1.2    NA
3    3   red    1.3    NA
4    4 green    1.4    NA
5    2  <NA>     NA     2
6    3  <NA>     NA     3
7    4  <NA>     NA     4
8    5  <NA>     NA     5
9    6  <NA>     NA     6
10   7  <NA>     NA     7
11   8  <NA>     NA     8
12   9  <NA>     NA     9
13  10  <NA>     NA     2
14  11  <NA>     NA     3
```

Comment: You shouldn't offer solutions requiring retired packages!